# How to run Sublime Text 2 through vagrant

Tags: sublimetext2, vagrant

I've set up a 32-bit version of Ubuntu through Vagrant. My plan was to now install Sublime Text 2 on this box. I downloaded the 32-bit Linux version of Sublime Text 2 and placed it in the root directory. Through synced folders I then moved it to /opt. Trying to run sublime text through /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text yields the result "sublime_text: command not found". I am lost as to what I have to do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

symI think the command for sublimetext may be subl? It is on Arch atleast.

**EDIT**: Ah, you can make a symlink

`sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl`

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-open-sublime-while-on-the-vagrant-server) says you can't access sublime on vagrant machines unfortunately.